# Extension of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: real-analysis

The problem states:

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$ with $n\ge2$. Recall that, according to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $p(x)$ has $n$ number of roots in the complex number set. Suppose all roots of $p(x)$ are real and distinct. Prove that the roots of $p'(x)$ are all real.

I know and kind of understand the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, but I do not know how to extend it to  $p'(x)$. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Show that there is a constant $c $ such that $p/c $ has real coefficients, and apply the familiar real variable theory from calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p(x)$ has $n$ real roots: $a_1 <a_2 <\dots <a_n$, then we may write $p(x)=a \prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)$. It now suffices to show that the derivative of  $q(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ has $n-1$ distinct real roots. On each $(a_i,a_{i+1})$, by Mean Value Theorem, there exists a number $c$ where $q'(c)=\frac{p(a_i)-p(a_{i+1})}{a_i-a_{i+1}}=0$. Thus $q'(c)$ has at least $n-1$ distinct real roots, and these are all the roots of $q'(x)$ since it is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Comment: That theorem you are trying to use needs the polynomial to be real.

Comment: Oh, you are correct! I did not read the question carefully.

Comment: But this is not a problem (as pointed out by Andrés E. Caicedo in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

By Rolle's theorem, the polynomial has a stationary point between every pair of real roots. As there are $n-1$ such points, this exhausts the roots of $p'$.